# C++ Class Method Running before other Method

Tags: c++

I have used this site quite a bit in the past and never had to actually post a question before but I'm not sure how to phrase this simply.  I'm in a C++ class at Devry, the actually homework requirement side of my project is done but I'm adding some elements for practice.

So to go with the homework assignment I have added an additional class called Song.  It has 2 private variables (title and length) some basic constructors and operation overloads for = and ==.  That all works fine.  I then added an array of the Song class to the Cd class (max songs per Cd is 10).  I created a few new methods for Cd:

- addSong(Song s);
- removeSong(Song s);
- organizeSong();  and
- modified Report() const;

to write out the songs in order based on the number of selections there are.  The Cd private values of selection and playtime are now linked to the total number of songs and the total length of those songs respectively.  Everything works fine.  removeSong takes the specified song out of the list then calls organizeSong to set the remaining songs to the lowest values in the array.  However it seems wherever I call removeSong(Song s) from it removes it before any thing writes to the program.
So the following code will draw the information from the Cd, but only one of the songs despite the removeSong method being called after the Report method.  anyone got any ideas why that is?

```
Song s1("Hey Jude", 4.52);
Song s2("The song of Pie", 3.14);

Cd c1 ("Beatles", "Capitol");
c1.addSong(s1);
c1.addSong(s2);
cout<< "Using object directly: \n";
c1.Report();

c1.removeSong(s1);
```

the Report method looks like this:

```
void Cd::Report () const
{

    cout<< "Performers: " << performers << endl << "Label: " <<label << endl << "Selections: " << selections <<endl << "Playtime: " << playtime << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < selections; i++)
    {
        cout << "Song " << i+1 << ": " << song[i].getTitle() << " Length: " << song[i].getLength() << endl;
    }

}
```

to clarify.  I have tested this with more songs, and without the removeSong method being called and it will write out all the songs in the array.

EDIT****  I am adding the rest of my code to hopefully clarify my question.  I'm not yet interested in making it thread safe or more efficient, it has no purpose besides demonstrating inheritance and composition of classes to my instructor both of which it already does beyond what our assignment asks.  I appreciate the comments on how to make the code better and will be looking into those things but I'm trying to figure out why removeSong is effecting the output of Report when Report comes before removeSong in the main code.  I have tested the different methods and overloads and they all work as they are supposed to, it is only the timing of when removeSong occurs that I am interested in.  It removes the correct song and rearranges the existing songs correctly, it just does it to soon: before the first Report is called.  (I do need to change the uppercase in report for consistency).  I'm mostly certain this is something basic that I am missing being new at this.

main code:

```
// GSP125_Davis_lab4_partA.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <conio.h>
#include "classic.h"
#include <string.h>
///Prototypes
void Bravo(const Cd & disk);

Song s1("Hey Jude", 4.52);
Song s2("the Song of Pie",3.14);
Song s3("National Anthem", 5.55);

char* userInput = "null";
char str[20] = "null";
bool bol_end = false;
int main()
{

    Cd c1 ("Beatles", "Capitol");
    c1.addSong(s1);
    c1.addSong(s2);
    c1.addSong(s3);
    Cd *pcd = &c1;
    Classic c2("Piano Sonata in B flat, Fantasia in C", "Alfred Brendel", "Phillips");
    c2.addSong(s2);
    c2.addSong(s3);
    c2.addSong(s1);

    cout << "Using object directly:\n";
    //this is where the code seems to have an issue. as you see Report is called
    //then after c1.removeSong(s1) is called.  s1 is removed properly but this first
    // c1.Report() reflects the changes removeSong makes.
    c1.Report();
    c2.Report();
    c1.removeSong(s1);

    cout << "Using type Cd method for cd object:\n";

    pcd->Report();
    pcd = &c2;
    pcd-> Report();

    cout<< "Calling a function with a Cd reference argument:\n";
    Bravo(c1);
    Bravo(c2);

    cout << "Testing assignment: \n";
    Classic copy;
    copy = c2;
    copy.Report();

    cout << "Press any key to continue...";
    _getch();
    return 0;

}

void Bravo(const Cd & disk)
{
    disk.Report();
}
```

Cd.cpp

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "cd.h"



Cd::Cd(char * s1, char * s2) 
{
    strcpy(performers, s1);
    strcpy(label, s2);
    selections = 0;
    playtime = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < songLimit; i++)
    {
        song[i] =  Song();
    }
}
Cd::Cd(const Cd & d)
{
    strcpy(performers, d.performers);
    strcpy(label, d.label);
    selections = d.selections;
    playtime = d.playtime;
    for(int i = 0; i < songLimit; i++)
    {
        song[i] = d.song[i];
    }
}
Cd::Cd()
{
    strcpy(performers, "None");
    strcpy(label, "No one");
    selections = playtime = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < songLimit; i++)
    {
        song[i] = Song();
    }
}

Cd::~Cd(void)
{
}
void Cd::Report () const
{

    cout<< "Performers: " << performers << endl << "Label: " <<label << endl << "Selections: " << selections <<endl << "Playtime: " << playtime << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < selections; i++)
    {
        cout << "Song " << i+1 << ": " << song[i].getTitle() << " Length: " << song[i].getLength() << endl;
    }

}
void Cd::addSong(Song s)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < songLimit; i++)
    {

        if (song[i].getTitle() == "none")
        {
            song[i] = s;
            selections++;
            playtime+= s.getLength();
            break;
        }
    }
}
void Cd::removeSong(Song s)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < songLimit; i++)
    {
        if(song[i] == s)
        {
            song[i] = Song();
            selections--;
            playtime-= s.getLength();
            break;
        }
    }
    organizeSong();
}
void Cd::organizeSong() 
{

    int empty = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < songLimit; i++)
        {
            if(song[i].getTitle() == "none" && empty == -1)
            {
                empty = i;
            }
            else if (empty != -1)
            {
                song[empty] = song[i];
                song[i] = Song();
                empty = i;
            }
        }

}
Cd & Cd::operator=(const Cd & d)
{
    strcpy(performers, d.performers);
    strcpy(label, d.label);
    selections = d.selections;
    playtime = d.playtime;
    for(int i = 0; i < songLimit; i++)
    {
        song[i] = d.song[i];
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Song.cpp

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "Song.h"



Song::Song(char* s, double l)
{
    title = s;
    length = l;
}

Song::Song(const Song & s)
{
    title = s.title;
    length = s.length;
}
Song::Song()
{
    title = "none";
    length = 0;
}

Song::~Song(void)
{
}

char* Song::getTitle() const
{
    return title;
}
double Song::getLength() const
{
    return length;
}
Song & Song::operator=(const Song & s)
{
    title = s.title;
    length = s.length;
    return *this;
}
bool & Song::operator==(const Song & s)
{
    bool result = false;
    if (title == s.title && length == s.length)
    {
        result = true;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Again I appreciate the attempts to make the code more efficient or make more sense but I am already doing more than the teacher has asked us to.  I just want to know if there is an obvious reason for why the song is being removed before Report displays in the first time even though Report comes first in the code.

Comment: Numerous problems with that code, TBH. `1.` The collection used shouldn't be an array if you want to remove from the middle. `2.` `Report` should use a for loop over the container, not be limited by some arbitrary variable. Take a look at `std::set`.

Comment: I am sure there is a lot wrong with the codes efficiency, however that is not relevant to my current homework assignment nor the mystery of of why the removeSong is taking effect before the Report.  Also removeSong has code to organize the array, that works fine.  I did try using a list but there are things there I don't know how to work with yet and I don't intend of going that far off pace with the class yet.  So I'm alright with the efficiency issues for now, but is that what is causing removeSong to occur before Report?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your implementation, it was hard to answer your question, so I wrote it as I imagine it should look like. I've made a few improvements, though:

1. `3.14` doesn't mean "3 minutes and 14 seconds". At best, it means 3.14 minutes, which is 3 minutes and 8.4 seconds. I've changed that to unambiguous `chrono` primitives
2. Removing the song by value was ambiguous because of unclear equality relationship between the songs. I've noticed you had overloaded `operator==`, but I can't see a way how this could be *reasonably* implemented. Adding an unique id to every Song would be a way to solve it, but I didn't feel entitled to it, so I settled on removing by index (which also models the CD itself pretty well).
3. The collection **is not thread-safe**. Don't forget about that.
4. I don't know why `report` was uppercase, but I changed that to keep consistency.

I wasn't sure how the reorganization inside of the CD was supposed to work, so I just skipped that part.

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <functional>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iterator>

// C++14-like shim
// in C++14 just use min and s
constexpr std::chrono::minutes operator "" _min(unsigned long long m) {
    return std::chrono::minutes(m);
}
constexpr std::chrono::seconds operator "" _s(unsigned long long s) {
    return std::chrono::seconds(s);
}

class Song {
public:
    std::string title;
    std::chrono::seconds length;

    Song(std::string title, std::chrono::seconds length) :
        title(std::move(title)), length(length) { }
};

class Cd {
    std::list<std::reference_wrapper<Song>> songs;
    std::string performer, title;

public:
    void addSong(Song & s) {
        songs.push_back(std::ref(s));
    }
    void removeSong(unsigned n) {
        if (n >= songs.size())
            throw std::out_of_range("The song of given index doesn't exist on that album");

        songs.erase(std::next(songs.begin(), n));
    }
    void report() const {
        std::cout << title << ", " << performer << '\n';
        for (auto const& song : songs) {
            std::cout << song.get().title << " " 
                      << song.get().length.count() / 60 << ":"
                      << song.get().length.count() % 60 << '\n';
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    Cd(std::string performer, std::string title) :
        performer(std::move(performer)), title(std::move(title))
    { }
};

int main() {
    Song s1("Hey Jude", 4_min + 52_s);
    Song s2("The song of Pie", 3_min + 14_s);

    Cd c1 ("Beatles", "Capitol");
    c1.addSong(s1);
    c1.addSong(s2);
    c1.report();

    // this doesn't work anymore because of the reasons described above
    //c1.removeSong(s1);
    c1.removeSong(0);
    c1.report();
}
```

Comment: More like... 3 minutes and 8.399999983749288 seconds. Also, the class is **just** not threadsafe, not only because the interface doesn't allow race-free query/update.

Comment: The values are arbitrary, just to represent use of variables and class declaration.  It's a vary basic class I am in so we are just now learning about inheritance and composition.  I never like the use of double to represent time but that was the teachers choice, I appreciate the example of how to use chrono.  I'll post the rest of the code I am using and maybe it will clarify my question.  I don't even know what threadsafe is yet, but I'll look into it.  I know it doesn't effect this current project.